# how can i do "find.element.by...." in a while loop?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Using Selenium python, i am tring to loop through a page clicking in every "Text link", while exists a "Text link"

Code:

```
while(driver.find_element_by_link_text("Txt link") == True): 
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Txt link").click()
```

> Error mensage
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "phishing.py", line 8, in
>   
>       class report(unittest.TestCase):   File "phishing.py", line 26, in report
>       while(driver.find_element_by_link_text("Ver mais...")):   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 389, in find_element_by_link_text
>       return self.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 855, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 308, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 194, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link
>   text","selector":"Ver mais..."

Comment: Hi Pedro, what is the error message?

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit: 1. Do you mean that there are more than 1 element with `"Txt link"`? 2. Is element actually a *link* (e.g. `<a href="#">Txt link</a>`)? 3. Does clicking element re-directs you to another page?

Comment: Hi, i have a list of elements bellow all for elements i hava a link text "see more", if i click it, it shows me 4 more elements and if i click it again it shows me another 4 elements, in this case i have to click 3 times but it will constantly change, clicking see all "see More" allows me to run through the page and search all data i need

Comment: How many times you want to click it? Will it be disabled after all data eventually displayed and there is nothing to show? Share HTML code sample for the mentioned link

Comment: in this case i have to click 3 times, if there is no data to show, the link text do not show up 

sorry, i cant share the html code my friend

Answer (score 1):

if we use `while(driver.find_element_by_link_text("Txt link") == True):  or  while(driver.find_element_by_link_text("Txt link").is_displayed() == True):`

let say if element is not displayed, then? it will throw exception right? so go for WebDriverWait to wait for element.

In Java, i use try/catch and place while in try if i expect some times that element may not available but still i need to move further.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can solve the issue:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

while True:
    wait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Txt link"))).click()
except TimeoutException:
    break
```

This should allow you to click the link while it is available

Answer (score 0):

The following statement will throw noSuchElementFoundException when it is not able to find the webElement on a given page. You have to catch that exception to avoid execution halt.

```
   driver.find_element_by_link_text("Txt link")
```

And *you have to correct your loop logic to a finite state. You cannot run a loop on a single item without specifying initial count and increment strategy.*

Answer (score 0):

You have to use FindElements instead of findElement store it in a list and iterate over the list using a for loop. Every time you are trying the same element and that's the issue.

Using FindElements it will take all your element in a list and your problem will be solved.

@note: After clicking on the link if a new browser window is opening, you need to handle that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use of time sleep is necessary especially for huge pages with many clickable elements. Because, when the first click is conducted, the page must be loaded for second click.

```
import time
while(driver.find_element_by_link_text("Txt link")):
   driver.find_element_by_link_text("Txt link").click()
   time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just created a good workaround. The code below will refresh the page every ten seconds looking for the desired element. Looping for a max of 400 seconds

```
    y = 1
    while y < 400:

        try:
            driver.refresh()
            driver.find_element_by_link_text("Txt link").click()
            y = 401
        except:
            time.sleep(10)
            y = y + 10
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try below code :-

```
 while(driver.find_element_by_link_text("Txt link").is_displayed() == True): 
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Txt link").click()
```

Comment: What are the benefits of this approach? `is_displayed()` will not protect you from `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: File "phishing.py", line 26, in report
    while(driver.find_element_by_link_text("Ver mais...").is_displayed() == True):
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Ver mais..."}

Comment: You need to add wait before above mention step to make it present